# Can't grab and move a maximized window using the mouse

Tags: indicator

I am using 11.04 and I have global menu's disabled *(don't remember which method I used to accomplish this)*. I have the system tray set to allow all apps, using a method I found on [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html) and I have *"minimize to tray"* add-on for Mozilla Thunderbird which is set to close Thunderbird to the system tray instead of quitting/closing it.

**Problem:** If I minimize or close any application to the system tray without first un-maximizing the application's window, I am not allowed to grab any open app's window that is maximized by the title bar using the mouse. I have to first un-maximize the app to move it. ***But,*** if I minimize an app to the unity launcher bar instead of the system tray from any position (be it maximized or not) I don't have any problems.

How do I make the applications behave the same way when minimizing/closing them to the system tray?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can always move a window by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> while grabbing any part of it.

Comment: when i close any apps window from its maximized state to the system trey, i am no longer able to grab any other maximized apps window by the title bar and move it/unmaximize without hitting alt. Now if i close any apps window to the system tray from a non maximized state i dont have any problems grabbing other maximized apps windows and moving/unmaximizing it.

Comment: THANK YOU @Mauricio!!!!! I just installed latest Ubuntu for the first time and I opened Thunderbird and the bloody window opened with the whole left half of it outside of the left side of the screen and i couldn't even see the titlebar so i couldn't drag the window, thank you for posting this, I was finally able to move teh widnow!

Comment: @Mauricio, any idea how I can make all windows startup at the location they were last at? I mean, whenever i open a new app, it opens at very top-left of screen. I always move all windows to center of screen but next time i open them they're back to top-left again. How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to be able to move maximized windows.  Any sane window manager disables moving maximized windows.

Comment: you can move maximized windows, every OS i have ever used allows maximized windows to be moved, of course when you move the maximized window it is no longer maximized. Windows does this, and ubuntu does this. I can't speak for Mac as i avoid using mac's intentionally.

Comment: That's like saying I can drive a car with no engine - all I have to do is add an engine first. ;) I'm on a Windows XP system at work right now, and cant grab and drag a maximized window - the "move" option in the right-click menu on the title bar is also greyed out, like it's supposed to be. On the Ubuntu 11.10 system using Unity which is right next to me, if I try to drag a maximized window, it first unmaximizes, and then lets me move the non-maximized window. But that's *not* moving a maximized window. I don't remember OS X letting me move maximized windows either, but it's been a while.

Comment: But, to be more useful, I'll note that Ubuntu 11.10's Unity minimizes to the tray by default - no extra plugin is needed.  So probably the easiest way to fix this behavior is to upgrade to the current release; lots of Unity stuff from 11.04 was better polished in this release. :)

Answer (score 0):

I frequently encounter the same problem… not being able to drag using the title bar… (on Ubuntu Mate 16.04)

- I have "Toggle Fullscreen Mode" set to <kbd>shift-F11</kbd> in my Keyboard shortcuts.
- Additionally, <kbd>F11</kbd> is often some native command to maximize Windows (browsers, IDEs, Caja, …)

The result of the two often slightly vary, i.e. Toolbar/Bookmarks still present on fullscreen, etc… the first is just an outer window-manager-ish full screen, the 2nd an implementation of „full screen mode“…

**Having said that:**

Trying one or the other or both shortcuts after each other eventually gets me back to a large, but draggable window…